# Conditional formatting based on CONTENT with jQuery / Javascript when parsing xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, formatting

Conditional formatting jQuery / Javascript when parsing xml seems easy, but trying to do Conditional formatting based on CONTENT with jQuery / Javascript just don't work, I mean I can't get it to work... .-)

If I want to change color of output () according to xml file content inside tag Groups

$(data).find('Kurssi:has(Group:contains("red") ---> do something ($("h3").css("color",...)
$(data).find('Kurssi:has(Group:contains SOMETHING ELSE ---> do nothing...

This must be very simple, but I have been trying like millions of different syntaxes, with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Not my brightest moment... I was trying to format something which wasn't created yet...

Much easier after the html element is created :-)

Sorry to waste your time.